# How to adapt 12-2 ceiling light circuit to LED light fixture's smaller guage push in WAGO connectors

Tags: led, junction-box

I am replacing an older incandescent fixture that had a box in the ceiling with wire nuts connecting to the 12-2 romex in the box.

The [new fixture](https://hw.menardc.com/main/items/media/FEITE001/Install_Instruct/3491381_MANUAL.pdf) is an LED with integrated JBox.  There are "WAGO" push in connectors in the this integrated JBox.  The problem is that the 12-2 conductors do not even come close to fitting into the push in connectors.

How do I solve this?  Can I chop the connectors off and wirenut the 12-2 to the smaller fixture wiring, all inside the jbox?

Comment: I'd be shocked if Feit used actual Wago connectors. Lookalike knockoff, I'd believe.

Comment: Do not know wago connectors, but seems funny that they would not fit common wire gauge(maybe they are more picky than wire nuts).  Would phone/contact the company before cutting(destroys the guaranty).  With the other comment, use google to find correct contact info for Feit.

Comment: Don't really care about the warranty on a 14 dollar light..

Comment: You could pig tail (if there's room in the box) some 14 ga to the 12 and then connect to the push in connectors.   I don't particularly care for the push in connectors even though the current is very low for an LED.  I'd just cut them off, strip the wires pretty long so you have plenty to wrap around that 12ga and use an appropriately sized wire nut.  ...just my opinion, not an "answer".

Comment: The last box of (real) Wago connectors I bought were for sizes up to 12 gauge (forget how small they went since it was not relevant). Are you lifting the tab up all the way before inserting the wire?

Comment: These say WAGO on them and I looked it up by the number on the part ... 16 to 20 guage range

Comment: Kind of stupid to use connectors that will not even fit the smallest allowable house gauge(14).  I would check if that light is even legal for sale/use(UL listed, real UL).  Insurance could deny any claims if they find it.  Denying claims is what insurance lives for.

Comment: @chad well, there's the problem right there. Yes, FEIT erred and supplied the wrong connector, since lighting circuits must be #14-#12 (and rarely, #10).

Comment: If they're truly Wago connectors, there's no need to cut anything, just open the clamps and take them off. Oddly, the picture in the instructions in step 4 showing the wiring leading into the box shows a round cable, not a flat cable as is normally used in the US. This product might be designed for an international audience with more of a European focus than US focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cut off the push-in connector and use (the correct size) wirenut. That is, the wirenut you use much list one 12 AWG (solid or stranded, depending which you have, though most are good with both) and one whatever tiny size wire the fixture uses as a correct application of the wirenut.

Provided that the Romex is temperature rated for the integrated J-Box, wich the fixture literature says should be 75C.

Comment: Is this safe to do with in the "integrated j box"

Comment: Probably. Does the integrated J-box have instructions printed on it regarding how many wires of what size are allowed in it?

Comment: Alternatively, if the integrated J-box only allows a single 14-2, you could  replace the original J-Box and use 14 AWG from that to it - **if and only if** you change the breaker on this circuit to 15A, not 20A.

Comment: it only says minimum 75C supply conductors and 90C vapor barrier .. No idea why it's talking about a vapor barrier.  The wiring is old UF actually ... from early to mid 80s ... no temperature rating on it, but to my thinking an LED is going to go less hard on it than the incandescent fixture

Comment: The fixture wires are 18awg and it appears there are wirenuts rated for 12 and 18 so that part is doable.  Concerned about temperature rating on 12-2 (old UF cable, from 80s) inside the plastic Jbox on the fixture ...

Answer (score 0):

This fixture is a version of a recessed can retrofit intended to be installed directly to an open drywall ceiling, not mounted to a box like a traditional light fixture.

[Link to a random retailer's product listing](https://www.johnplylerhomecenter.com/RETROFIT_CAN_JBX_LED_3K_5_6IN_p/7420102.htm)

Wiring connections aside, unless you can remove the existing box, you are going to have problems mounting this.

Comment: I removed the box ... I can put the box back if necessary.  The box is out of the way.  I'm just concerned over how to connect the 12-2 to the smaller guage connector ...

Comment: Ah, OK.  In that case, yes you can absolutely replace the connectors - as Ecnerwal stated, make sure that the wirenut is rated for the number and gauge of wires you are using (that long list on the back of the box/tub will tell you) and you'll be good.  Don't forget to also install the correct Romex bushing for the KO in the box.